# Async stack traces in debugger are not available on 32bit platforms. The feature is disabled

Tags: node.js, debugging

Even though I have a 64-bit system, this error is shown

> Async stack traces in debugger are not available on 32bit platforms. The feature is  disabled.

I don't understand why. Someone please explain

Comment: You probably downloaded a 32bit version of node.

Comment: Running VS code on a 64 bit platform windows, but **remote** debugging the node-red JS code on a Raspberry Pi (32 bit linux without GUI) makes impossible to "download 64 bit".

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem recently. Apparently I had the 32bit version installed on my x64 system and installing the 64bit version of Node.js cleared the error for me.